# How can access this sub array of response in Retrofit in this code?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I am totaly beginner in Retrofit.I am trying to make object of the following response in using the retrofit annotations.

**Response:**

```
{"status":"1",
              "data":[{"title":"hb","rate":"12",
                                               "pic":[{"file_name":"x"},{"file_name":"y"}]}
                     {"title":"hk","rate":"15",
                                              "pic":[{"file_name":"x"},{"file_name":"y"}]}                                              
                     {"title":"hc","rate":"18",
                                              "pic":[{"file_name":"x"},{"file_name":"y"}]}

                    ]                       
}
```

For that i wrote code to display it in recycler view.
**By writing the following code i able to get the elements of data object but can't access the elements of pic object of the response.
What should i edit in this code to access the elements of pic object?**

**Book_Hotel.java:**

```
public class Book_Hotel extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private Recycler_Adapter adapter;
    private Api_Contact con;
    private Api_Interface apiInterface;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book__hotel, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Room List");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        apiInterface = Api_Client.getApiClient().create(Api_Interface.class);
        Call<Api_Contact> call = apiInterface.getContacts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Api_Contact>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Api_Contact> call, Response<Api_Contact> response) {
                con = response.body();
                Log.e("data", con.getData().toString());
                adapter = new Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(), con.getData());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Api_Contact> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("fail", t.toString());

                if (t.toString().contains(" Unable to resolve")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet connect prob", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Api_Client.java:**

```
public class Api_Client {
    public static final String BASE_URL="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static  Retrofit getApiClient(){
        if(retrofit==null){
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
            Log.e("in client",retrofit.toString());
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**Api_Contact.java:**

```
public class Api_Contact {
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String Status;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<data> Data;
    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public List<data> getData() {
        Log.e("in get data of contact", Data.toString());
        return Data;
    }
}
```

**Api_Interface.java:**

```
public interface  Api_Interface{
    @GET("xxxxxxx")
    Call<Api_Contact> getContacts();
}
```

**Recycler_Adapter.java:**

```
public class Recycler_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Recycler_Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<data> data;
    Context context;
    public Recycler_Adapter(Context context, List<data> contacts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = contacts;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.roomlist_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Recycler_Adapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.price.setText(data.get(position).getRate());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title, price;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.awesom);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
        }
    }
}
```

**Please help me to solve this.That will be appreciated.Thank you.**

Comment: Can you post the code for your `data` class?

Comment: Already posted.

Comment: I am not seeing a class definition that looks like:
`public class data {
...
}`

Comment: The Data came from the server gets stored in the con (object of Api_Contact.java) (see in the Book_Hotel.java file's onResponse method ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
public class Api_Contact {
  @SerializedName("status")
  private String status;
  @SerializedName("data")
  private List<Data> data;

  public String getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public List<Data> getData() {
    Log.e("in get data of contact", data.toString());
    return data;
  }

}
```

And you need to create this another two classes:

```
public class Data {

  @SerializedName("title")
  private String title;
  @SerializedName("rate")
  private String rate;
  @SerializedName("pic")
  private List<Pic> picList;

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public void setRate(String rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
  }

  public void setPicList(List<Pic> picList) {
    this.picList = picList;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public String getRate() {
    return rate;
  }

  public List<Pic> getPicList() {
    return picList;
  }

}
```

And

```
public class Pic {

  @SerializedName("file_name")
  private String fileName;

  public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
  }

  public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
  }

}
```

Comment: Yeah i know this ,but now then how to get the data in onResponse method like right now i have added the code for data object array,but how can i access the pic object elements.

Comment: If you did exactly this, you just need to call response.body() and you will have the Api_Contact object. To access pic elements you can do con.getData().get(index).getPicList().get(index).

Comment: i tried but it shows NullPointerException on that line.

Comment: In witch call you are getting null pointer? getBody()? getData()? getPicList()? Make sure that you are truly receiving this JSON with those fields, you can use Postman to know if the request is right.